# Android Studio onClick button to display ImageView in another activity

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have setup 2 activities - one and two .

For activity 1, I have a `EditText` and a button. When user open the app, it will show Activity One(just like the screenshot) to prompt user to key in a number. For example, 1 or 2.

What I am trying to do is that: I want to display a `ImageView` in activity 2 when user key in a number in `EditText`follow by a click on the button in activity 1.

- If user key in 1, it will display `1.png` in activity 2
- If user key in 2, it will display `2.png` in activity 2
- If user key in 3, it will display `3.png` in activity 2
  etc...

the image will get from `drawable` folder.

**Please refer to this screenshot**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**I can pass the integer value through `Intent` from activity 1 to 2 but I can't do it for ImageView**. so that means the if else loop i have already done just that the `ImageView` cant display.

```
 get_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.1); //  here i can only key in 01 ( it will get image from Drawable folder 1.png). i cant put int value into it.
```

Or i shouldn't use get_image.setBackgroundResource?? Anyone can help? I stuck here for 1 day...

thanks in advance!

please check screenshot -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/53vjy.jpg

Comment: please post the code in activity2

Comment: post code for button click of Activity 1 and code for Activity2

Comment: did you tried my answer?? http://stackoverflow.com/a/38342869/3981656

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that you can pass integer value from activity 1 to 2 so just use that to find your image.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
if(1 == yourValue) { 
//set 01.png 
} else {...}
```

I may missing somethings because i can't understand when you said that "but i cant do it for imageview".

EDIT: after your addtional code.
So you must map your integer value with your resource file name. You could not put your integer value to get_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.id).
I think in your situation you should use an array just store id of resource you need `int[] drawableIds = {R.drawable.01, R.drawable.02}` in your Activity2 
and then use like this `get_image.setBackgroundResource(drawableIds[yourIntegerValue-1])` (ofcourse  you should take care array out of index when you use this method).

Comment: sorry, i forgot to type some important info -> get_image.setBackgroundResource()

Comment: i edited my answer after you add more information. And i think you should use setImageResource instead of setBackgroundResource

Answer (score 2):

Try below code for your solution,

**For Activity One write below code to redirect on activity 2**

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
      intent.putExtra("SelectedNumber", editText.getEditableText.toString());
      startActivity(intent);
```

**Now In Activity 2 write below code in onCreate method**

```
     int selectedNumber = 1;
      if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
      {
          selectedNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("SelectedNumber");
      }

      switch(selectedNumber)
       {
            case 1:  // set your 01.png Image
                     break;
            case 2:  // set your 02.png Image
                     break;

            // And so
       }
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to type some important info -> get_image.setBackgroundResource()

Answer (score 2):

Try this way might helps you.

```
String mDrawableName = "1"; //editText.getText().toString();
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

then your Activity2 use,

```
 setImageResource(resID); 
(or)
 setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resID));
```

Finally,

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String mDrawableName = editText.getText().toString();
    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());

    Intent ii=new Intent(Activity.this, Activity1.class);
    ii.putExtra("resId", resID);
    startActivity(ii);
}
});
```

> Activity2

public class Activity2 extends Activity
{
    private ImageView img;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intent);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    Intent iin= getIntent();
    Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        int drawableId =(int) b.get("redId");
        img.setImageResource(drawableId); 
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to type some important info -> get_image.setBackgroundResource()

Answer (score 1):

you can pass resource value in extras. try this way.

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEdittext);
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);

                if(edit.getText().toString().trim().equals("1")){
                    i.putExtra("image", R.drawable.01);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(edit.getText().toString().trim().equals("2")){
                    i.putExtra("image", R.drawable.02);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Valid Value.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

and in your **ActivityTwo.java**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
imageView.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("image",0));
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to type some important info -> get_image.setBackgroundResource()

Comment: I recommend you to use `setImageResource` rather then `setBackgroundResource` but still if you want to use that just replace `setImageResource` with `setBackgroundResource` in my code.

Comment: Thanks you! this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

In activity 2's on create

```
get_image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

then use switch case for values from intent then

```
  switch(intentValues){
    case 1:
     get_images.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.1));
    break;
    case 2:
    get_images.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.2));
    break;
    }
```