# Android Studio onClick button to display ImageView in another activity (part 2)

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I think i didn't describe properly what i meant in this [question part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342718/android-studio-onclick-button-to-display-imageview-in-another-activity) . So i enter more details here . Please have a look .

activityOne.java

```
EditText get_input;
Button get_button;
String display;
int image_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    get_input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_year);
    get_button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_submit);

    get_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            int store_get_input=Integer.parseInt(get_input.getText().toString());
            int results;
            results=store_get_input%12;


             if (results == 0) {

                    display = "Your number is "store_get_input";
                    image_id=0;

                } else if (result ==1){

                    display = "Your number is "store_get_input";
                    image_id=1;

                }else{

                    display = "Your number is others";
                    image_id=3;
                }

            Intent home_intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Result_page.class);
            home_intent.putExtra("home_store_get_input",display);
            home_intent.putExtra("home_store_image_src",image_id);
            startActivity(home_intent);

        }
    });
}
```

activityTwo.java

```
public class Result_page extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView get_result;
ImageView get_image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_page);


    get_result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_result);
    get_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    Intent result_intent=getIntent();
    String text=result_intent.getStringExtra("home_store_get_input");

    get_result.setText(text);// display what the user has enter

    // get_image.setImageResource  
    //OR other coding to display imageview by using the image_id from activty 1? 
}
```

From both java files, i think it will be clearer and easier for u guys to read. So i stuck at activityTwo.java the last past where I need to key in some codes in order to display the imageview by uising int image_id or other coding.

Comment: Why not just edit the two questions to have one coherent one?

Comment: Edit first question. no need to post 2 parts

Comment: I don't see a question in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need 2 duplicated questions.

**Method 1:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/38342798/2670771

**Method 2:**
In activity 1 just send image id to activity 2

```
if (results == 0) { 
   display = "Your number is "store_get_input";
   image_id = R.drawable.image0; 
} else if {...}
```

In activity 2 get image id from intent

```
int defaultIdWhenCouldNotFindImageSourceId = -1;//should use a negative value 
int imageId = result_intent.getIntExtra("home_store_image_src", defaultIdWhenCouldNotFindImageSourceId);
if( defaultIdWhenCouldNotFindImageSourceId != imageId) {
    //when you can find an valid image id in intent extra, display it
    get_image.setImageResource(imageId);
}
```

Comment: btw, the coding is working. But i dont understand the "-1" and the "if statement ". can you explain more about it ? thank you .

Comment: you can use any value you want instead of -1 (because when you look at getIntExtra method, it require a "defaultValue" when it can not find home_store_image_src in intent extra) but shouldn't use positive value because it may be an object id in your project).
I will edit my code to let you understand it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to integer in second activity and use a switch case for selecting image based on that number. Like :

```
Intent result_intent = getIntent();
String text = result_intent.getStringExtra("home_store_get_input");
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(text);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   //Exception
}
int imageId = R.Drawable.default_image;
switch(number) {
    case 1:
           imageId = R.drawable.image1;
           break;
    case 2:
           imageId = R.drawable.image2;
           break;
           ........so on
}
ImageView.setImageResource(imageId);
```